# In google script, I am using appendRow to put data in a worksheet from another worksheet, however, it just inserts the row as blank. where is mistake?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to programming in general so I simply got my code from youtube, however, appendRow doesn't work, as in it displays inputted info as blank but takes space anyway. I know that it is blank and takes space since I have a formula that displays the name and ID, and surprisingly it correctly displays the name and ID, but there are other information which I didn't include within the formula.

I made the code almost exactly like the one from youtube and has shown to work, until I made the same code but for different information entirely (Financial info). And the appendRow for the financial code works perfectly, so I am very confused as to how the first code isn't working.

Here is the code I use to save an entry:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

const forumWS = ss.getSheetByName("Forum")
const behindthescenesWS = ss.getSheetByName("BehindTheScenes")
const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Data")

const idCell = forumWS.getRange("C5")
const searchCell = forumWS.getRange("C3")

const fieldRange = ["F5","C7","C9","F7","F9"]

    function SaveRecord() {

  const id = idCell.getValue()
  
  if(id == ""){
    createNewRecord()
    return
  }

  const cellFound = dataWS.getRange("A:A").createTextFinder(id).matchCase(true).matchEntireCell(true).findNext()

  if(!cellFound) return
  const row = cellFound.getRow()
  const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => forumWS.getRange(f).getValue())
  fieldValues.unshift(id)
  dataWS.getRange(row,1,1,fieldValues.length).setValues([fieldValues])
  searchCell.clearContent()
  ss.toast("Changes Saved!","ID:" + id)
}

function createNewRecord() {
  const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => forumWS.getRange(f).getValue())

  const nextIDCell = behindthescenesWS.getRange("B3")
  const nextID = nextIDCell.getValue()
  fieldValues.unshift(nextID)

  dataWS.appendRow(fieldValues)
  idCell.setValue(nextID)
  nextIDCell.setValue(nextID+1)
  ss.toast("New Record Created","ID:" + nextID)
}
```

Everything here works except the appendRow. To be completely honest, I'm not sure if I would be able to even understand the responses, so if you can, pretend that you're explaining to a 5 year old.

If you want the second code for the financial stuff to compare, then here it is:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

const forumWS = ss.getSheetByName("Forum")
const behindthescenesWS = ss.getSheetByName("BehindTheScenes")
const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Data")

const idCell = forumWS.getRange("C5")
const searchCell = forumWS.getRange("C3")

const fieldRange = ["F5","C7","C9","F7","F9"]
const data2WS = ss.getSheetByName("Data2")

const idCell2 = forumWS.getRange("N5")
const searchCell2 = forumWS.getRange("K3")

const fieldRange2 = ["K5","K7","K9","N9"]
function SaveTransaction() {

  const id = idCell2.getValue()

  if(id == ""){
    CreateNewTransaction()
    return
  }

  const cellFound = data2WS.getRange("A:A")
                      .createTextFinder(id)
                      .matchCase(true)
                      .matchEntireCell(true)
                      .findNext()

  if(!cellFound) return
  const row = cellFound.getRow()
  const fieldValues = fieldRange2.map(f => forumWS.getRange(f).getValue())
  fieldValues.unshift(id)
  data2WS.getRange(row,1,1,fieldValues.length).setValues([fieldValues])
  searchCell2.clearContent()
ss.toast("The current record of the transaction has been edited!","ID: " + id)
}

function CreateNewTransaction() {
  const fieldValues = fieldRange2.map(f => forumWS.getRange(f).getValue())

  const nextIDCell = behindthescenesWS.getRange("D3")
  const nextID = nextIDCell.getValue()
  fieldValues.unshift(nextID)

  //console.log(fieldValues)
  data2WS.appendRow(fieldValues)
  idCell2.setValue(nextID)
  nextIDCell.setValue(nextID+1)
  ss.toast("A new transaction has been recorded!","ID: "+ nextID)
}
```

Here is also a picture of what the blank row looks like. I have no clue why it enters it twice.
[Empty rows below filled rows from when it was working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DINDm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const fsh = ss.getSheetByName("Forum")
  const bsh = ss.getSheetByName("BehindTheScenes")
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  const idCell = fsh.getRange("C5")
  const searchCell = fsh.getRange("C3")
  const fieldRange = ["F5", "C7", "C9", "F7", "F9"]
  const id = idCell.getValue()
  if (id == "") {
    const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => fsh.getRange(f).getValue())
    const nextIDCell = bsh.getRange("B3")
    const nextID = nextIDCell.getValue()
    fieldValues.unshift(nextID)
    dsh.appendRow(fieldValues)
    idCell.setValue(nextID)
    nextIDCell.setValue(nextID + 1)
    ss.toast("New Record Created", "ID:" + nextID)
    return;
  }
  const cellFound = dsh.getRange("A:A" + dsh.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(id).matchCase(true).matchEntireCell(true).findNext()
  if (!cellFound) return;
  const row = cellFound.getRow()
  const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => fsh.getRange(f).getValue())
  fieldValues.unshift(id)
  dsh.getRange(row, 1, 1, fieldValues.length).setValues([fieldValues])
  searchCell.clearContent()
  ss.toast("Changes Saved!", "ID:" + id)
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper,  sorry fo the extremely late reply, I've found out something recently actually, both our codes work (except mine enters the data twice for some reason), the problem is that the information is displayed at the bottom of the spreadsheet instead of directly below the information, its super weird, thanks for the code above, and sorry to ask but do you know anything about that?

Comment: Hi to all, problem is fixed now. It was a problem on my end with invisible functions making the information appear at the bottom. Still, thank you, @Cooper for fixing the double entry problem, I appreciate it.